# How to reset the Recent Files Only filter in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, filter, project-navigator

The Project Navigator has this nifty filter at the bottom (icon with a clock). When you click it, it only shows the files which have been edited recently.

Problem: There seems to be no way to reset this. My project has nearly 200 source files and I use a lot of them from day to day. So this list is getting bigger and bigger, and therefore less useful over time.

Often I am just done with something and then I'd just want to get rid of these files in the recents filter.

Is there a secret way to reset the filter? Xcode4 must store this information somewhere.

Comment: I have the reverse problem; I'm working on perhaps 20 files out of a codebase of a couple of hundred and some keep disappearing from the filter list when I want them to stay there! I submitted an enhancement request -bug report for this; suggest you do the same..

Comment: did you ever find anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate into the `.xcproject` or `.xcworkspace` package using the terminal or open package in Finder. Clear the contents of the `<username>.xcuserdata` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, and apparently Apple fixed the bug.  Just click on the clock icon again to toggle.

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting Xcode (I'm using 7.2) reduces the number of files shown when the "recent files" filter is on.  But I don't know how the files that still remain are determined.